# Use rotary switch potentiometer from amplifier as main power switch

Tags: power-supply, switching

I am working on a battery powered audio project that uses a cheap amplifier ([PAM8403 5V Mini 2*3W D Class Digital Amplifier Board](https://www.amazon.de/ZkeeShop-10PCS-PAM8403-Digital-Amplifier/dp/B072KL1MXD/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1543740658&sr=8-15&keywords=class%20d%20amplifier%203w)). 
The volume can be changed using a rotary switch potentiometer.

Now I would like to use the switch of the potentiometer to be the main switch for my project.
The ultimate goal is to drive the enable pin of the [Adafruit PowerBoost Charger](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465) by the switch of the potentiometer. The BowerPoost Charger is OFF when the enable pin is connected to ground (the switch is closed - reverse logic). I measured 5V between the pins of the switch when it's turned off, and 0V (switch is closed) when it's turned on.

So how do I have to connect the potentiometer to the charger board?

Answer (score 2):

remove R13 from the powerboost and connect your switch between `Vs` and `EN`

[image]

a resistor from `EN` to `GND` may be required to cause a shutdown, the datasheet was not clear on that point. if needed try 100K.

Comment: Wouldn't there be the possibility of injecting noise into the audio or affecting the function of the potentiometer? I would like to see a more complete answer explaining how this will work.

Comment: potentiometer swiches are isolated from the signal terminals, also the enable signal is DC and the poersupply is ultrasonic so any noise should be inaudible.